# How to allow reset password for users with unusable password in Django?

Tags: django, authentication

I have a web application Django 1.4.3. We allow users to book shows as guests; such users are created with email and unusable password ( using set_unusable_password() ). Now, we want to allow them to reset password. But, the Django's built-in reset form disallows to reset for user's with unusable password. Do I have to create my own form? What are the alternatives? Or Should I use make_random_password?

Relevant Code from auth project -

```
if any((user.password == UNUSABLE_PASSWORD)
           for user in self.users_cache):
            raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['unusable'])
```

thanks

Answer (score 7):

The default `PasswordResetForm` does not allow users to reset their password if their current password is unusable. However you can subclass the form and override the method that does this check.

For Django 1.8+, override the [`get_users`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.7/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L215) method.

In your case, for Django 1.4, override the [`clean_email`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.18/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L198) method.

Then include your custom form in your `password_reset` url pattern, as the kwarg `password_reset_form`.

Comment: Thanks! Will try out your suggestion.

Comment: Successfully implemented! Cheers!!

Comment: @BreakingConstitution Please accept this as the answer :)

Comment: @alasdair is this  still the best way to handle this in Django 2.0? Trying to get this working and would love the help :)

Comment: @franciscojavierarceo the Django 1.8 approach of overriding `get_users` will still work, it still exists in the upcoming Django 3.0 release. If you need more help it would be better to ask a new question.